# How do I compare a Webelement and int in python selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I used find_elements_by_class_name to gather all the information I needed in a website, and wanted to take a value off of that information. Let's say I have the information of different types of cards. Every card has a value, and I want to do something with the cards with a value of 100 or higher. A fraction of my code is:

```
kakera = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('grid-1nZz7S')
for elementos in kakera:
    valor = elementos.find_element_by_tag_name('strong')
    print (valor.text)
    if valor.get_attribute('value')>100:
           print("Its over 100")
```

I used print `(valor.text)` to see the value of a card (in this case, the card has a value of 105), and tried everything that I imagined to compare the value of the card and 100, and print `("It's over 100")` just to see if the code works. But python can't compare `WebElement` and `int` objects. What should I do to compare them?

Answer (score 0):

See the below line in your code,

```
if valor.get_attribute('value')>100:
           print("Its over 100")
```

Basically you are trying to compare `string` with an `int`, you can not do that.

instead, you could try with `int()`, see below :-

```
if int(valor.get_attribute('value'))>100:
               print("Its over 100")
```

Comment: Hi, the method you suggested didn't work for me, but I was able to solve it with this:     if int(valor.text)>100:, thank you for your comment anyways!